# Concatenate strings for variable identifier in PHP

Tags: php, variables, while-loop

I know this is not the proper way to do this, however I am trying to put a quick fix on a form that was done by another developer.  Basically I want to add an incremental number to a variable inside a while statement:

```
$count = 1;
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $variable . $count = $r['somefield'];
        $count++
}
```

So that makes the variables:

$variable1
$variable2
$variable3
....etc

Comment: Basically any time you need variable variables, you're doing something wrong. Use arrays. That's what they're for.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  As I stated.. I know it is the completely wrong way to do it. I just needed a quick fix for a form that another developer had done with some 400 fields and NO ARRAYS!!  For this case, variable variables saved me some 4 or 5 hours from having to rewrite the entire structure of the form.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I must have read your post too fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$varname = 'variable' . $count;
$$varname = $r['somefield'];
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: This solved my dilemma!  Thank You! I hate it when I open up a script that was written years ago by an inexperienced developer.

Comment: @Prince, I can really feel your pain. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off with an array...

```
$variable[] = $r['somefield'];
```

You can use variable variables, however it is probably not a good idea, especially for a trivial case like this one.